# Spring not converting JSON Array to List of user defined objects

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

So I have a input Json data-

```
[
  {
    "Id": "30B05CEC6808F81C7A8B",
    "eventType" :"TestEventType"
  }
]
```

And a wrapper class-

```
public class CancelSeatEventDtoWrapper {

    List<CancelSeatEventDto> cancelSeatDtoList;

    public List<CancelSeatEventDto> getCancelSeatDtoList() {
        return cancelSeatDtoList;
    }

    public void setCancelSeatDtoList(List<CancelSeatEventDto> cancelSeatDtoList) {
        this.cancelSeatDtoList = cancelSeatDtoList;
    }
}
```

And a POJO

```
public class CancelSeatEventDto {

    private String eventType, Id;

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
}
```

And in a Spring controller one of the method has -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/teams/id.do", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public String deleteId(@RequestBody CancelSeatEventDtoWrapper jsonValue)
```

After running it i get a 400 Bad Request error.
Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: The 400 error means the caller isn't passing the callee the appropriate RequestBody/method.  Any chance you could give an example of how the controller is called?

Comment: @Pedantic I am calling the controller using the postman rest client. For Example if the Controller class has a mapping of "/deleteSomething" and my method has the mapping of "/teams/id.do" . The url would be http://localhost:8080/myApp/deleteSomething/teams/id.do. And in the request body I am passing the jason as shown above. Other methods in the controller which takes simple String are working fine for me. It is just this method that expects a list of object thats not working